# Need to make a gridview with two static text fields

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview

Hello i need to make a gridview like the following images with static textviews.[image]

I need to make it in Portrait mode. I know there are lot of guides available on stackoverflow on how to make a gridview with two textviews but i am unable to follow them and failed many times trying to create a gridview exactly like this. Instead of marking my post as negative if someone could help me build a gridview like above i will be really great full.
Thanks!

Edit: I have tried a TableLayout in order to achieve the above layout and things are going well except i cannot draw a vertical line(divider). See the image below:[image]

My Code:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:divider="#FF909090"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:stretchColumns="1"
android:background="@drawable/custom_background"
android:showDividers="middle">
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:padding="3dip" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Imran"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>

<View
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:background="#FF909090" />

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:padding="3dip" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Test"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>

<View
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:background="#FF909090" />

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:padding="3dip" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Test"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>
```

Thanks to all for helping me out.

Comment: maybe just show some code which you tried? then we can point you what is wrong with it... (screens also welcome)

Comment: @snachmsm Please see my edited post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in the assumption that you need to use a `GridView` here.

**What you presented should be done with a `ListView` or, even better, a `RecyclerView`.**

Try looking at each row as a list item and the task will become really easy :-)

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: You are welcome :-) If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as correct :-)

Comment: But how am i going to make a ListView or RecyclerView exaclty like above?
If you have some guide or you can redirect me to one then i will be really great full.

Comment: Create a child layout (two TextViews), create an adapter, provide data to the adapter - standard way :-) StackOverflow is NOT a tutorial site, it is a site for solving specific problems. There are many tutorials for RecyclerViews on the Internet :-)